# Spring boot on aws eks with helm chart

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

When I deploy spring boot application on aws eks using helm chart. I am having the error below, not sure if I was missing some configuration on aws eks:

```
│   Type     Reason            Age                  From                                                     Message                                                                                           │
│   ----     ------            ----                 ----                                                     -------                                                                                           │
│   Warning  FailedScheduling  18m                  default-scheduler                                        0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match pod affinity/anti-affinity, 1 node(s) didn't sati │
│ sfy existing pods anti-affinity rules.                                                                                                                                                                       │
│   Normal   Scheduled         18m                  default-scheduler                                        Successfully assigned tee/*****-services-576d5cddfd-vfls4 to ip-192-168-8-0.ap-southeast-1.comput │
│ e.internal                                                                                                                                                                                                   │
│   Normal   Pulling           18m                  kubelet, ip-192-168-8-0.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal  Pulling image "061424976585.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/*****/*****-service:1.0.0-SNAPSH │
│ OT-69c97"                                                                                                                                                                                                    │
│   Normal   Pulled            18m                  kubelet, ip-192-168-8-0.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal  Successfully pulled image "061424976585.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/*****/*****-service: │
│ 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-69c97"                                                                                                                                                                                        │
│   Normal   Created           18m                  kubelet, ip-192-168-8-0.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal  Created container *****-services                                                                  │
│   Normal   Started           18m                  kubelet, ip-192-168-8-0.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal  Started container *****-services                                                                  │
│   Warning  Unhealthy         3m2s (x60 over 17m)  kubelet, ip-192-168-8-0.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal  Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503
```

Actually I have no idea about this. Posted the question here with the hope that will have someone is familiar with spring boot and eks know the root cause. Thank you in advance.

Comment: looks like the service/application failed to start. for details you'd need the logs/console output (from the instance).

Comment: The docker image that is created, try to run that in a container locally. Looks like your application entrypoint is not correctly defined.